# pass a pointer value in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

i just learn the objc language,so my question is kind stupid,but still i very curiosity,I want pass a objc instance pointer to another variants,so i can do this in the C

```
char *astr = malloc(sizeof(char) * 90);
void *copystr = astr;
sprintf(astr, "hello %s", "me");
// insert code here...
NSLog(@"|%s| copy to |%s|", astr, copystr);
```

but in objc,it's not work in any way.

```
NSString *conststr = @"ha!damn!dead!";

//if we pass the pointer to anoter
id *otherSpaceStr = conststr; //this is noway to work
void thirdSpaceStr = conststr; //void won't work too
```

so my question is after all,them all are pointer,why can't pass them.
[image]
[image]

i look into the debug windows,found them not only pointer,them seems have type too
[image]

Comment: You don't use an asterisk (`*`) with `id`. You just want `id otherSpaceStr = conststr;`.

Comment: @maddy you r right!but why still the void *point not work anyway?

Comment: For `void` you need the asterisk. `void *thirdSpaceStr = conststr;`.

Comment: @rmaddy you are right!it work!but need a little chage
        void *thirdStr = (__bridge void *)(mayAstr);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because `id` is already a pointer. From the Apple Documentation.

```
typedef struct objc_object *id;
```

As you can see, `id` means "a **pointer** to any type". This means that when you assign your `NSString` to `otherSpaceStr` (previously `id *`), you are assigning it to a pointer *to a pointer*.

```
 NSString *conststr = @"ha!damn!dead!";     // pointer to NSString
 id otherSpaceStr = conststr;               // pointer to anything
```

So just remember, `id` is already a pointer, and there is no need for *two* levels of indirection (`id *`).

Comment: hey!amazing!so the objc make the id simple use,it worked!thank you!